# Poner todas las letras que están en mayúscula de un color en css

Tags: html, css

```css
div::first-letter {color: tomato;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="encabezado">RapiNoticias</div>
</form>
```

¿Cómo puedo poner las 2 letras que están en mayúscula en color "tomato"? (sería la letra R y la letra N en este caso).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes encerrar la letra deseada en una etiqueta `span`, cuyo uso básico es el de poder formatear parte de un determinado texto de forma independiente...

```css
div::first-letter {color: tomato;
font-size: 40px;
}
span {color: tomato;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="encabezado">Rapi<span>N</span>oticias</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buscando solución a [una pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/604440/5896) a esta *sobre cómo cambiar el estilo de la primera letra de cada palabra*, he modificado ligeramente [esta respuesta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531791/2553194) de forma que se establezca un formato distinto - color tomato, en este caso - para todas las letras mayúsculas que se encuentren dentro de un texto determinado.

La mejora respecto a la solución aceptada es que las etiquetas `<span>` se generan automáticamente. No hay que enmarcar manualmente aquellas letras que queramos cambiar de color. El código cambiará todas las mayúsculas que encuentre.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-tomato")
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/([A-Z])([a-z]+)?/g, "<span class='letra-tomato'>$1</span>$2")
  }
}
```

```css
.letra-tomato {
    color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<p class="bloque-tomato">Todas LaS mayUscuLAS en coloR TomaTo!</p>
```

La parte javascript del código lo que hace es recuperar todos los elementos de la clase bloque-tomato, que son aquellos sobre los que queremos aplicar nuestro algoritmo.

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("bloque-tomato")
```

Sobre cada uno de esos elementos encontrados, reemplazamos su contenido aplicando una expresión regular:

```
 "/([A-Z])([a-z]+)?/gm"
```

En dicha expresión se distinguen dos partes: ([A-Z]) que significa letra mayúscula y ([a-z]+) que significa todas las letras minúsculas que vengan a continuación. La primera parte se asocia a $1 al reemplazar y la segunda a $2

```
<span class='letra-tomato'>$1</span>$2
```

La parte de /g significa global [No pares en el primer match, continua reemplazando]. De forma que todas las letras mayúsculas se verán enmarcadas automáticamente en etiquetas `<span>` que le aplicarán el formato.

Creo que algo así es lo que estaba intentando adaptar KamiSama con peor fortuna.