# Primera letra más grande

Tags: html5, css3

actualmente necesito poner la primera letra de cada palabra conformada en un frase de mayor tamaño que el resto, teniendo en cuenta que todas están en mayúsculas. Esto es lo que he intentado:

CSS

```
    h1::first-letter {
   
    font-size: 150%;

    }
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="sombreado">AJEDREZ POR ORDENADOR</h1>
```

Pero este comando solamente me está afectando a la primera letra, y no a todas las primeras letras de ese h1.
El resultado tendría que ser algo así (pero todo en mayúsculas):

Ajedrez Por Ordenador

Comment: Esta respuesta seguro que te ayuda... https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/565552/263891

Comment: Revisa esta  [liga](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter), le voy a que es por el tipo de etiqueta, intenta con un P en vez de con un H1

Comment: Buenas, Héctor, no sé si la respuesta indicada es lo que estabas buscando. Justo estaba adaptando una respuesta de StackOverflow cuando se ha cerrado esto. Aquí tienes un fiddle que te pone todo el texto en mayúscula y te permite aplicar un estilo distinto a la primera letra https://jsfiddle.net/ox246mg3/ Sin tener que asignar manualmente spans. Está basado en este respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531791/2553194